# Coefficient stability test in panel model in R

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

I want to test whether a pooling multivariable OLS panel regression contains any structural breaks between two time periods, i.e. should I run two separate regressions for these two periods presented in my panel data.

It could be smth like Chow test, but the regression residuals are not distributed normally.

Plm package contains 'pooltest' function to run poolability test. But I'm not sure about how it works. It is described as F test as well (like Chow), testing similarity of coefficients across individuals (and nothing about "across time"). At the same time, it uses pvcm as a reference model, and pvcm seems to be able to estimate time effects. Unfortunately I fail to find any information to make clear is it good for "time poolability" as well (assuming that I can fix residuals problem).

CUSUM test seems to be often used to check model parameters stability, but I am very new to this and don't know what assumptions should be met here and does CUSUM fit my case, and how to implement it in R correctly.

Is it better to try to make the regression have normally distributed residuals and choose 'pooltest' function, using pvcm model with time effects as an argument? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: You do not mention whether you have panel data or not (but apply the `panel-data` tag). Package `strucchange` could to be what you are looking for https://cran.r-project.org/package=strucchange

Comment: Yes, it's panel data, have fixed this in the question. I know the strucchange package, and I tried to find any examples or recommendations of appyling any method of sctest function to panel data, to learn about probable specific details, but with no results

Answer (score 0):

As you are referring to function `pvcm` from package `plm`: the development version of the package now has the chi-sq test for parameter homogeneity of the Swamy (1970) random coefficents model (`pvcm(. , model = "random"`) when you print the model's summary.

Example output (test result in last line given), but I will put the line I mean here upfront as well:

> Test for parameter homogeneity: Chisq = 25554.4 on 329 DF, p-value: <
> 2.22e-16

```
summary(greene.pvcm.re)
Oneway (individual) effect Random coefficients model

Call:
pvcm(formula = form.greene, data = Produc, model = "random")

Balanced Panel: n = 48, T = 17, N = 816

Residuals:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.23533 -0.06035  0.08087  0.09229  0.20421  0.97490 

Estimated mean of the coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.6530780  1.0833134  1.5259  0.12702    
log(pc)      0.0940755  0.0515162  1.8261  0.06783 .  
log(hwy)     0.1050114  0.1736406  0.6048  0.54534    
log(water)   0.0767189  0.0674273  1.1378  0.25520    
log(util)   -0.0149021  0.0988643 -0.1507  0.88019    
log(emp)     0.9190594  0.1044486  8.7992  < 2e-16 ***
unemp       -0.0047055  0.0020673 -2.2761  0.02284 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Estimated variance of the coefficients:
            (Intercept)    log(pc)   log(hwy) log(water)  log(util)   log(emp)
(Intercept)   50.101152 -0.1269537 -5.7011050  1.1490999  0.9323094 -1.5405556
log(pc)       -0.126954  0.0921826  0.0050351 -0.0178555 -0.0306629 -0.0649625
log(hwy)      -5.701105  0.0050351  1.2347643 -0.1657787 -0.4550976 -0.0467022
log(water)     1.149100 -0.0178555 -0.1657787  0.1883437 -0.0095582 -0.1125142
log(util)      0.932309 -0.0306629 -0.4550976 -0.0095582  0.3996351  0.0118384
log(emp)      -1.540556 -0.0649625 -0.0467022 -0.1125142  0.0118384  0.4348876
unemp         -0.027161 -0.0013129  0.0020316 -0.0024191 -0.0013977  0.0068745
                  unemp
(Intercept) -0.02716134
log(pc)     -0.00131287
log(hwy)     0.00203161
log(water)  -0.00241907
log(util)   -0.00139775
log(emp)     0.00687449
unemp        0.00016044

Total Sum of Squares: 21431
Residual Sum of Squares: 36.691
Multiple R-Squared: 0.99829
Chisq: 434.623 on 6 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
Test for parameter homogeneity: Chisq = 25554.4 on 329 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```